# Environment Keyring Issues: The key {9ef91d59-7718-4765-a8a0-da0e4cd0069a} could not be found in the key ring. Something went wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Question: I have been using the Elastic Beanstalk service for multiple users. While Elastic Beanstalk successfully creates one instance, I encountered key ring issues when attempting to reset my password. After clicking the 'Forgot Password' link and trying to reset my password, I received key ring-related errors. However, when I repeatedly click the 'Reset Password' button, the password is eventually successfully reset.

I need to retrieve a key from the Elastic Beanstalk environment server in my .NET startup file. How can I achieve this?

I am used this way to get key from elastic bean server.

```
string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "3b6b8e3c-4873-4f87-9826-222d3753ac90.xml");

            if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
            {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
                XElement keyElement = xmlDoc.Descendants("key")
                    .FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Attribute("id")?.Value == "3b6b8e3c-4873-4f87-9826-222d3753ac90");

                if (keyElement != null)
                {
                    string keyValue = keyElement.Element("descriptor")
                        .Element("descriptor")
                        .Element("masterKey")
                        .Element("value")
                        ?.Value;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue))
                    {
                        services.AddDataProtection()
                            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "keys")));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?